# How to create a user in Oracle that could only view the source code without changing them and view table fields?

Tags: oracle

How to create a user in Oracle that could only view the source code of packages and procedures without changing them and view table fields but not the data in tables?

I know that you could grant a view to specific user, but how to deny access to tables data without hiding fields?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a role to view data dictionary info. So the user will be able to view the definition of the tables, view, packages, system objects, etc.

```
grant select_catalog_role to user;
```

Or the `Select Any Dictionary` grant.

But with this grants the user will be able to see many more data than he needs. 
An alternative is to grant select on DBA_SOURCE, DBA_TABLES views.

See a discution on dba.stackexchange.com [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1295/how-do-i-allow-users-to-see-grants-view-definitions-pl-sql-etc-in-a-database).

Comment: I need access that gives the right to execute certain query and see the resulting fields, but not the data. Is such access possible in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.
You need to create a view on DBA_SOURCE and grant a user SELECT on this view. In that case user will be able to see the code of packages and procedures and table structures, but not execute them.